# Does such a vector field exist?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

Does there exist a velocity field $\mathbf{u}(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $$\text{Div}\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla w_1\\
\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla w_2\\
\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla w_3\\
\end{bmatrix} = \text{Div}\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{w}\cdot \nabla u_1\\
\mathbf{w}\cdot \nabla u_2\\
\mathbf{w}\cdot \nabla u_3
\end{bmatrix} $$
where $$\mathbf{w} = \nabla \times u   = \operatorname{Curl}(\text{u})$$ and in this context $\mathbf{w} = (w_1,w_2,w_3)$. Let $D_\textbf{v}(f)$ denote the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction of the vector field $\mathbf{v}$ then for each point in time $t>0$ we have $$\text{Div}\begin{bmatrix}
D_\mathbf{u}\left(w_1\right)\\
D_\mathbf{u}\left(w_2\right)\\
D_\mathbf{u}\left(w_3\right)
\end{bmatrix} = \text{Div}\begin{bmatrix}
D_\mathbf{w}\left(u_1\right)\\
D_\mathbf{w}\left(u_2\right)\\
D_\mathbf{w}\left(u_3\right)
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Using Einstein notation we can write this simply as $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} D_\mathbf{u}\left(w_i\right) =  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}D_\mathbf{w}\left(u_i\right)$$ where in this context of course $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_1} =  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x}$, $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_2} =  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial y}$, and $\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_3} =  \dfrac{\partial }{\partial z}$. Intuitively, this suggest that $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ are the same up to some constant vector $\xi$. Can we show that $\mathbf{u} = \mathbf{w} + \xi$? This not general true for arbitrary fields unless their curl is the same.

Comment: I thought about breaking down into cases when u and W are linear independent and when they are linear dependent. But the curl may always be linear independent.

Comment: TeX note:  $\nabla\mathbf u$ `\nabla\mathbf u`, not $\bigtriangledown\textbf{u}$ `\bigtriangledown\textbf{u}`.  I have edited accordingly.  Also, I'm pretty sure you meant [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), not Eisenstein notation, so I changed that.